# How to use variable volume control for mac via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, macos, volume

I found this code in python to control mac volume:

```
osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 35")
```

I want to use a variable to control this volume instead like:

```
volumes = [35, 35, 30, 35, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 40, 45, 45, 45, 45, 55, 45, 50, 45, 50, 55]
for i, n in enumerate(frequencies):
    osascript.osascript("set volume output volume %s" (volumes[i]))
```

I'm getting this error though:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is there any way I can input volume directly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the `%` after the string

```
"set volume output volume %s" % volumes[i]
```

The C-style string format support number formatting:
`%d` for integers, `%f` for floats, ... and further padding,  formatting functionalities. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), [PEP 3101](https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, got it working through:

```
osascript.osascript("set volume output volume " + str(volumes[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

import os

volume = 50 # Set this number between 0 & 100

os.system('osascript -e "set Volume %d"' % math.ceil((8 * volume) / 100))
```